# laravel queue job , Dispatch two argument

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

this is my controller

```
SmsAdsJob::dispatch('aaa','bbb');
```

this is my job

```
    protected $request;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $clients=$this->request;

        logger($clients);
    }
```

this is logger

```
local.DEBUG: aaa
```

Problem is in controller I dispatch two value but in job I get One value,But I should get two value in job, can you give some advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmsAdsJob should have two properties in It's constructor. Then you can access them. I don't understand why you are using "request" in the Job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SmsAdsJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $a;
    private $b;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($a,$b)
    {
        //
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo $this->a,PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->b,PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Please check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Answer (score 2):

You Can pass your params in an array or object datatypes. For instance:

```
$params = ['aaa', 'bbb']
SmsAdsJob::dispatch( $params );
```

Or:

```
public function __construct($param1, $param2)
{
    $this->param1 = $param1;
    $this->param2 = $param2;
}
```

When you pass to variables you should consider that your **job class** must know **how many params** do you want to **receive**.